# create JSONObject and JSONArray in Liferay Portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Which is the best option to create a `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` in Liferay portlet?

You can't do `Java` simple way:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray();
```

Error:

> Cannot instantiate the type JSONObject
>
> Cannot instantiate the type JSONArray

---

Tried with `JSONFactoryUtil` and it works but its deprecated.

**com.liferay.util.json.JSONFactoryUtil**

```
JSONObject json = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
JSONArray arrayJson = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
```

Comment: JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject() deprecated? It's the only and right way now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject()` and `JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray()` are not deprecated, neither in Liferay 6.x nor in Liferay 7.x.

If you still want to use `new JSONObject()` and `new JSONArray()`, you can import [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20190722).

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20190722</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
compileOnly group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
```

Try a different version if this version doesn‘t work for you.

Comment: Thanks! i was using `com.liferay.util.json.JSONFactoryUtil` package, its deprecated but replaced with `com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil`. [Source: com.liferay.util.json.JSONFactoryUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/util/json/JSONFactoryUtil.html). I realized thanks to your answer.